# When giving property value for JanusGraph,only first 20 characters are getting stored as value in the property using Java

Tags: java, string, properties, character, janusgraph

Im creating a graph using JanusGraph.Creating a Vertex and added a property to it.I have assigned value to the property.The value is having more than 20 characters. After the graph commit, when I query the particular property of the graph, Im getting only first 20 characters.

Kindly help me on How to store more than 20 characters as a value to the property.

PFB the example for the above scenario

```
//Creating Graph       
public JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("janusGraphBatch.properties");
JanusGraphManagement manageSystem = graph.openManagement();

//Adding Vertex
Vertex remitterV= graph.addVertex();

//Adding value(more than 20 characters) to the Property "NAME"
remitterV.property("NAME", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

manageSystem.commit();

//Querying property "NAME"

  System.out.println("Value for NAME Property:"+remitterV.property("NAME"));


  Result:
  Value for NAME Property:abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

Comment: You printing the property which defaults 20 chars. Do this instead:
`System.out.println("Value for NAME Property:"+remitterV.value("NAME"));`

Answer (score 4):

You're using the `toString` method because of the `System.out.println` there. That calls the `StringFactory` in TinkerPop.  [The string factory method cuts off after 20 characters](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/util/StringFactory.java#L105) If you call `.value()` you should get what you expect.

Comment: Hi Filipe  7pantalohnes,

Comment: And @Filipe Teixeira , Thanks for both of your Answers:). Yes that solved my Query.
Your Above suggestion is to get a value for single vertex property.
But my actual requirement is to get a PropertyKey,Value Pair List  of a vertex to frame a JSON for visualizing the Janus Graph in UI. For querying I’m using Gremlin pipe query. In the PropertyKey,Value pair  list, the Value should not be trimmed, if the character count is more than 20
Kindly provide your help.

Comment: To get PropertyKey,Value Pair List of the vertex,I 'm using the below code.
    vertex.property("NAME", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    vertex.property("ADDRESS", "1234567890123456789012345");
    vertex.property("CITY", "NewyorkTokyoParisQatarDelhiLondon");
    System.out.println("PropertyKey Value List:"+g.V(vertex).properties().toList());    
The Result is PropertyKey Value List:[vp[NAME->abcdefghijklmnopqrst], vp[ADDRESS->12345678901234567890], vp[CITY->NewyorkTokyoParisQat]]

Comment: In the above output, I'm getting all Key Values trimmed to 20 character.
In the above list,the Value should not be trimmed,if the character count is more than 20. This what I have asked in my first Post
Kindly help me in getting the PropertyKey Value List,without trimming

Comment: If you use the HttpChannelizer and POST your gremlin you can get back properly formatted JSON. The crux of your issue is still that you are using a `toString` method to print this value. The actual string values the vertex property objects are fine.